# Laravel Auth login validation editing

Tags: php, laravel, validation, authentication

I want to edit my laravel login form. The main problem if I input data in email and password fields (email is correct, but the password is incorrect). I get an error which shows that email is incorrect, not password... I found a solution, edit this method in AutenticatesUsers.php.
From:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
    ]);
}
```

To:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
        'password' => [trans('auth.failed_password')],
    ]);
}
```

But now if I do one mistake, no matter where I got both errors... How can I fix it? I want good inputs validation.

Edited: I'm overwriting sendFailedLoginResponse method like that:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::where($this->username(), $request->{$this->username()})->first();

    if(\Hash::check($request->$this->username(), $user->email)){
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]);
    } else{
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'password' => [trans('auth.failed_password')],
        ]);
    }
}
```

but now I'm getting this error: Object of class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController could not be converted to string

P.S. Sorry if questions are dumb, I'm new in all this Laravel and OOP stuff...

Comment: Throw 2 exceptions based of the failed value. If you put both conditions in the single throw, you'll get both back if it fails. I might go up in the stack to what is failing and calling that function

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you'd use validation itself, You should change `ValidateLogin` like this:

```
 $request->validate([                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
              $this->username() => 'bail|required|string|exists:users,username',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
              'password' => 'required|string',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
          ]);
```

With this change if the username not exists in your database laravel will throw exception which shows the username doesn't exists.
So when your flow comes to `sendFailedLoginResponse` you will be sure that just password is incorrect and you can throw exception just for password.

Comment: It works! Thanks. One more question. When the page is redirecting back with password error, still my email input field is auto-selected, where can I edit that?

Comment: for this one you need remove `$this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')]` from `sendFailedLoginResponse` method.